# Radio button value does not propagate to $scope

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to pick correct template on radio button click, but ng-model value does not propagate to $scope. here is my controller:

```
eventsApp.controller('FirstTestController',
function FirstTestController($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.menu = ['List', 'Table'];
    //$scope.checkedMenuItem = null;
    $scope.data = [
        { action: "Get groceries", complete: false },
        { action: "Call plumber", complete: false },
        { action: "Buy running shoes", complete: true },
        { action: "Buy flowers", complete: false },
        { action: "Call family", complete: false }];
    $scope.chooseTemp = function () {
        if ($scope.checkedMenuItem == 'Table') {
            return 'templates/testTemp.html';
        }else {
            return 'templates/listTemp.html';
        }

    };

});
```

here is my html:

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FirstTestController">
     <div ng-repeat="menuItem in menu">
              <label>
                  <input  type="radio" name="group" ng-model="checkedMenuItem"  value="{{menuItem}}" />
                  {{menuItem}}{{checkedMenuItem}}  </label>
          </div>
    <ng-include src="chooseTemp()"></ng-include>
   </form>
```

value of $scope.checkedMenuItem is always undefined.
Thank you.
Michael

Comment: because you need to use objects in `ng-model` not primitives. `ng-repeat` creates child scope

Comment: your comment helped me: I looked up how to access parent scope from child scope and it worked. Should be ng-model="$parent.checkedMenuItem"                                                                Thank you

Comment: no...should never use `$parent`...should define object on controller scope and use it instead. Can be empty object and `ng-model` will add the properties and values ... one object per form

Comment: Also makes sending form data much simpler...you send one object and done!

Comment: please mark question as answered when it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ng-repeat creates child scope, need to use $parent in ng-model to access parent scope. Thank to charlietfl, whose comment helped me to solve this.